# How to display base64 encoded image in HTML if it is located in a separated file?

Tags: html, image, apache, base64

I have base64 encoded image. If I put it right into html it works:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
```

But when I put all that base64 content into a separated file, it doesn't:

```
<img src="image.base64.txt"/>
```

I tried changing extension to .png, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Very likely a very stupid question, but is it supposed to work like that? I can't find any draft or RFC in regards of base64 data parsing in external resources, though my googling abilities sometimes can be compared to a camel's pi recital ability.
Also, the point of the data URI's as image (or object, or whatever) source is to reduce the number of connections to GET external resources; what would be the purpose of including base64 data in external resources? (not trying to play the smart, just asking :) )

Comment: @methode I don't know whether it is supposed to work or not, that's what I am trying to figure out :)

Comment: Oh, so that's why you asked! :) I'd be truly amazed if it would work, but since I neither know, +1

Comment: @serg have you figured out if loading base64 content from an external source is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to send the correct Content-type, Content-encoding and charset HTTP headers along with the file. Note that they are all part of the data: URI schema as well. You really should have a `charset=utf-8` or similar clause between the content-type and the encoding:

```
url(data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take on server side approach and just print the file into the `src` part of the `img` tag like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo file_get_contents('some/path/image.txt');?>"
```

Where your `image.txt` contains i.e.:
`data:image/png;base64,...`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, I believe. The first syntax corresponds to a pseudo protocol (scheme) [data:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format) that means that the data is not to be fetched from somewhere outside, but from the attribute string itself. As the "data" is in general binary, and the attribute is text, base64 is commonly used.

But when the data is fetched from outside the page (http server, or local filesystem), the data must come in raw (binary) form.

You could do it with some javascript work, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for my final year project at university, i was using XML doc's to link to a page and show the images in a canvas element. I made it so the image was searched for a variable, then assigned the variable with base 64 encoded image like so:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("test.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image");
txt=x[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.write(txt);

var card1 = txt;
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};
img.src= card1;
```