# MVC4 render image with Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Masters,

I have a scenario where i have a list of Items and on clicking single item it gets details along with image src url using ajax call.

I want to display(render) image right on page.

Now Image source URL is a FileActionResult returning Base64 string.

The problem is the page does not render image although it is having correct Src URL.
And I don't want any additional Ajax call.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why a base64 string when you can directly send an image stream as file result? any specific reason.
While a base64 works on <img src="data:image/png;base64,..."/> kind of funda.

Comment: [Ref 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917290/how-to-display-base64-encoded-image-in-html-if-it-is-located-in-a-separated-file) 
[Ref 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image) 
go through these two references.Might help you out. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you forcing the image to be updated?

The DOM is going to keep the image the same until you tell it to refresh the image -- I would suggest using something like

```
document.getElementById('theImg').src="/newImg.gif?unique=someuniquestring";
```

where `someuniquestring` is a new random datetime or something (to make sure browsers like IE don't cache the GET request).

Comment: But I am assigning it a URL that will definitely give you image. Something like <img src="/File/DownloadFile/1" />. If you punch same in another tab then it shows image. The only constraint is, the response is base64 string

Comment: Ah, so it's not exactly a File getting returned from your FileActionResult, is it?

Comment: File is returned as wanted if i open it in another tab but not rendering in Image box