# Can a html img tag read base64 files?

Tags: android, html, base64

Short question: Can a html img tag read a base64 encoded image file?

```
<img src='path-to-file/image.base64'>
```

Because I'm having trouble. It fires the onerror event but doesn't give a reason (well at least it doesn't say it couldn't find the file)

Oh! Some context: I'm trying to cache images to sdcard on android as base64 encoded files. That part works, but when I try to load the cached image it fails :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display base64 encoded image in HTML if it is located in a separated file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917290/how-to-display-base64-encoded-image-in-html-if-it-is-located-in-a-separated-file)

Comment: Well looking at the title you may be right. Will check. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) the answers give some pointers to how and what, but the TL;DR is using base64 is only for inline, as it's an encoded format that takes up more space, so if you use files anyways it doesn't make sense not to just save the actual images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turns out that base64 is only for inline use (or if you have the string you can set it with javascript)

So this works:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = base64_string;
```

But it doesn't work when you point the src to a file containing the base64_string

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "path/base64.txt";
```

PS: Thanks for the comments, this pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to source the image from inline data is:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="your image">
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use it inline, I want it to read the base64 string from the file. Or is this not supported?